# How to upgrade a full node after a snapshot?

Tags: iri-node, snapshot

I have a full node that runs on Linux Ubuntu. As I'm a Windows guy, I need someone to tell my how to upgrade my node to the newest IRI version and how to delete my database after a snapshot. I could of course re-install the whole server (I have installed it using the iota.partners tutorial), but as I'm sure it's just a matter of some commands in the console, I really hope someone would bother to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Usually after a snapshot an updated version of IRI, of the GUI wallet and of Javascript library are released. So you have to install the new version of IRI.

Actually upgrading is just a matter of replacing.

I usually install IRI cloning repository with `git` (and so first of all I rename for any eventuality the existing `iri` directory):

```
$ mv iri iri.old
$ git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/iri
$ cd iri
$ mvn clean compile
$ mvn package
```

Then:

- remove all files under `DB_PATH` directory if you configured `DB_PATH` to be outside the `iri` directory;
- remove all files under `DB_LOG_PATH` directory if you configured `DB_LOG_PATH` to be outside the `iri` directory;
- if you didn't set `DB_PATH` and `DB_LOG_PATH` these are automatically cleaned cloning the new repository (because these are under `iri` directory according to default configuration).
- On the contrary if you didn't set `IXI_DIR` outside `iri` directory you have to copy its contents from old IRI installation (from `iri.old` backup).

Also [this](https://medium.com/@ralf/prepare-for-the-january-28-2018-iota-snapshot-10f565b371ab) recent post could be of some help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help me out, but I'm sorry to say it didn't solve my problem. I need cut'n paste instructions like the ones at iota.partners. Maybe running Iota fullnodes is only for Linux/gnu fluent users...

Comment: You could explain what is your problem or delete current installation and follow iota.partners istructions from scratch (as you did before) using new version of IRI avalaible after the snapshot.

Comment: Yes, that's how I solved it. Re-installed from scratch. Worked like a charm (but not an elegant solution).
My problem is that I don't know where those directories are stored, and how to remove the files in them. I found some commands at a Linux website and sort of managed to upgrade, but afterwards my node was not able to sync anymore...

Comment: hi @MartinStormLarsen, section 7 in the [iota.partners instructions](http://iota.partners/index.html) actually include setting IRI to auto update. The command creates a cron job so would that not take care of the updating concerns?

Comment: The auto-update works fine with regular IRI updates, but won't delete my DB-folder. Instructions for this could be included in the iota.partners instructions...